# Sed regular expression with no letters matching letters

Tags: regex, bash, sed, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to look through a file and find all numbers greater than 16000 and replace them with the number 16000. I have been using sed and I created a regular expression

```
sed 's/[1]\{1\}[6-9]\{1\}[0-9]\{3\}/16000/g'
```

The problem with this is that it's matching things in the file such as A17890qr. I do not understand why I am matching this considering that my expression has no letters in it.

Sample Input

```
A17890qr,1000,17000,18000,1500,140,19900
```

Sample Output

```
A17890qr,1000,16000,16000,1500,140,16000
```

Edit: I have changed the regex to

```
sed 's/[^a-z A-Z][1]\{1\}[6-9]\{1\}[0-9]\{3\}/16000/g'
```

But now from the sample input I am getting the output of

```
A17890qr,10001600016000,1500,14016000
```

Comment: you need to add line/word anchors to avoid this.. adding few sample input lines and expected output will help in getting answers

Comment: Some sed features depend on OS.  What is your operating system?

Comment: Windows, I'm using the bash from the anniversary update

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In perl

```
perl -pe 's/\b\d+\b/$&>16000?16000:$&/ge' file
```

For every number bordered by a boundary checks if it is more than 16000 and replaces if so.

Comment: This works, but how would I incorporate this into a script? I have never used perl before.

Comment: I don't know what you mean? Just use it like any other command, or give an example in the question of how your script is set up and how it would be used.

Comment: So I have 2 parts. One is checking for numbers <150 and the other checking for numbers greater than 16000. I want to know how to put this command into a perl script to I run the script and it does this command of replacing numbers > 16000 and finding numbers less than 150.

Comment: I figured it out. I just took the command and put it into a bash script. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

With awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i){ if ($i ~ /^[0-9]+$/ && $i > 16000) {$i=16000}}}1' file
```

Output:

```
A17890qr,1000,16000,16000,1500,140,16000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/[^a-zA-Z][1]\{1\}[6-9]\{1\}[0-9]\{3\}/,16000/g'
```

this solves this exact problem but not when you try on

```
19000,A17890qr,1000,17000,18000,1500,140,19900
```

Output is

```
19000,A17890qr,1000,16000,16000,1500,140,16000
```

Comment: this happens because it is expecting some char to match so , is matching if A-Z are not present. So use awk instead. or modifying regex